# Critique: how to awesomize this logo?

Tags: logo, identity, critique

This is a course assignment (project) but with real client. 
The image shows the current logo, colourful text and the chimp as the letter "O".
I tried to make the (O) chimp face like other letters but it looked weird. so I made it as it is now.

I'm asking you guys to help me make it more appealing, the client insisted on making the tagline like handwritten and the 'O" as chimp face.

[image]

Logo design always appears to be easy, but it's not!

Regards.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you guys for your comments. What's your take on this revision? 
http://cl.ly/image/0K3R0F0F0I3A

Comment: Hey welcome to the community, as it is this question is a bit hard to answer. We don't really know what "appealing" means to you, or your client. Check out our critique guidelines and consider some key concerns you or your client had and it will be easier to offer feedback: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us generally what this company does? (on top of my head: I would simplify the chimp and maybe tone down/alter the tail-like effect of the letters. And I would move the blurb more to the left; it is a little heavy on the right side.

Comment: I just wanted to comment and make sure you mean `alley` as in a small pathway between two buildings, and not `ally` as in a friend or a mutual alliance.

Comment: It's not their official tagline, they told me to use it as it is, but I think it's ally. maybe because the client is a Finn.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there's way to much going on—I really don't know where to look first. Cut back on the number of colours. Make the monkey face really stand out by having the lettering be just a single colour. It's a good rule of thumb to have a single focal point in your logo, so as not to confuse the viewer where their attention should be.

Also, I've been taught to use text centering for wedding invitations and death circulars *only*, so you might want to think about left- or right-aligning your payoff. Also, if you use a more modest typeface on the payoff, more attention can go to the logo's focal point: the chimp.

Comment: Hi Bakabak, thank you for your comment. 
What's your take on this revision? http://cl.ly/image/0K3R0F0F0I3A

Comment: please include any updates in you orginal post, you can do so by clicking 'edit'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, need to say that current revision is not good in all and already dated. I would recommend to check the logos mostly oriented on web in actual size:

[image]

In such way you will see what is not good much clearer. So what I would suggest:

1. First of all, get rid this colorfull look. It can memorize test for color blindness.
2. I would recommend to change the font.. for example to something "cute" like Museo Rounded, etc.
3. I think lowercase will be better in this case.
4. Tagline.. It becomes almost unreadable. It is a good argument to force client to use normal font for tagline. In many cases logo will be used even in smaller size and tagline will be just like a dirt.
5. I would suggest to do flat monkey, more artistic and much more simple. For example: https://www.behance.net/gallery/8380403/Negative-space-animal-masterpieces

Looking forward your revisions!

Comment: Hi Vnovak, thank you for your feedback.
What do you think of this? 
http://cl.ly/image/0K3R0F0F0I3A